# invertible differentiable function proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f$ is an invertible differentiable function, that the domain of $f^{-1}$ contains an interval around $a$, and that $f^{-1}$ is continuous at a. Prove that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $a$ and that

$$ (f^{-1 })' (a )= \frac{1}{(f'(f^{-1}(a)))}.$$

I tried to use Chain Rule but that  did not worked out like I was expecting. Now I am thinking to use somehow that $x=f(f^{-1}(x))$ and $a=f(f^{-1}(a))$ but I am not sure how can anyone help me with this problem? I am so stuck right now... Thank you!

Comment: Hint: start with $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$, and use *implicit differentiation* to solve for $(f^{-1})'(x)$

Comment: Some MSE users tried to improve your post using TeX (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: everything looks fine to me, thank you for asking